# How to show Null instead of $0.00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Looking to get the following clause to show `Null` for `$0.00` values:

```
FORMAT(sp.SalesLastYear, 'c', 'en-us')
```

What function should I use?

Comment: You can use the `NULLIF()` function.

Comment: What did your research suggest? I note that this is your third question which shows no evidence of research. On this site you are expected to do your research, have a go and post a question when stuck on something specific. But really why are you trying to format data in SQL? Its a front-end job.

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous options, a couple would be

```
select Format(NullIf(sp.SalesLastYear,0),'c','en-us')

select case when sp.SalesLastYear>0 then format(sp.SalesLastYear, 'c', 'en-us') end
```